# Detecting version of NVCC in bazel

Tags: bazel

I want to detect in bazel what version of nvcc is installed in the system and set specifically flags based on the version. What is the best way to achieve that? I am pretty new to bazel build system.

Answer (score 2):

We have recently rolled-out Skylark remote repository and that's how we do auto-configuration for C++ so I guess that the best way to achieve that. See http://bazel.io/blog/2016/03/31/autoconfiguration.html